# Why Qt user interface looks different in Release mode than in Debug mode

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5

I am wondering why my user interface appears different (not so good looking) in release mode than in debug? Do I need to add some special dll to the release directory or to modify the project's .pro file?

Debug mode:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bidBB.png

Release mode:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/361Gr.png

This "release" user interface appears after adding the following necessary dll files:

```
platforms/qminimal.dll
platforms/qoffscreen.dll
platforms/qwebgl.dll
platforms/qwindows.dll
Qt5Charts.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5SerialPort.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
STDFU.dll
STDFUFiles.dll
STFFUPRT.dll
STTubeDevice30.dll
```

I have tried to add qwindowsvistastyle.dll, but the things look the same way.

Comment: have you added the qwindowsvistastyle.dll DLL in the styles folder? (styles/qwindowsvistastyle.dll)

Comment: From my experience, differences between release and debug mode occurs due to uninitialized variables. Depending on your configuration, uninitialized variables are treated different depending on the mode. So make sure all your members (esp. ints, bools, pointers) are initialized.

Comment: Generally speaking it's recommended to use [qtwindeploy tool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) however that doesn't seem to be a problem, it's more like something in your app is setting flat look and feel. Are you using QML or QtWidgets?

Comment: You almost definitely forgot some dll. Could also occur that you forgot stylesheet files or got trouble with resources in some other way. Widgets or QML? Anyway, comparing Debug and Release folders may help if it's not an initialization issue.

Comment: Just curious, do you know how did you manage to get the second view? It's beautiful an way better than the flat view. I tried very hard to get it back but it didn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it.

If the DLL files are from newer version of Qt in this case 5.11 and the EXE is compiled with the older version - 5.9, it seems that some of the DLL functions can't be used from the EXE and they are replaced with default ones. I've taken the DLL files from my Qt distribution and everything works well.